# Using sidenotes in mdframed environment

Tags: mdframed, tufte

I get problems when I try to use sidenotes in an mdframed environment:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newtheorem{mdtheorem}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{theorem}%
{\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=lightgray]\begin{mdtheorem}}%
{\end{mdtheorem}\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
test \sidenote{side note}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas how to get around this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The command `\sidenote` is equal to `\marginpar` or `\marginnote` which are not allowed in tables or boxes. So you can't use them.

The UK FAQ describes this error: [`! LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.`](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-fllost)